# Why doesn't list update after erasing element inside function?

Tags: c++, list

I am currently working on a project and have spent too much time trying to figure this out

**ItemOrdered.h:**

```
public:
    Item* getItem();
private:
    Item* item;
    int quantity;
```

**ItemOrdered.cpp:**

```
Item* ItemOrdered::getItem(){return item;}
```

**ShoppingCart.h:**

```
public:
    void addItemOrdered(Item* orderedItem, int quantity);
    void removeItemOrdered(Item* orderedItem);

private:
    list<ItemOrdered> orderList;
```

**ShoppingCart.cpp:**

```
void ShoppingCart::addItemOrdered(Item* orderedItem, int quantity){

    updateItemStock(orderedItem, quantity);
    ItemOrdered oitem(orderedItem, quantity);
    orderList.push_back(oitem);//This gets updated
}        


void ShoppingCart::removeItemOrdered(Item* orderedItem){

    list<ItemOrdered> :: iterator z;

    for(z = orderList.begin(); z != orderList.end(); ++z){

        if(z->getItem()->getID() == orderedItem->getID()){
            orderList.erase(z);//This does not get updated
        }
    }
}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
buyer1.getCart().showCart();//This shows the items ordered in the cart
buyer1.getCart().removeItemOrdered(pap2Pointer);//Remove this item from the *orderList*
buyer1.getCart().showCart();//Shows the same items, *orderList* was not updated
```

I cannot understand this. The main reason is that I had no problem with the function that added items into the *orderList*. It got updated normally. I tried any type of change to the *orderList* inside the **removeItemOrdered()** function but to no avail.
I cannot understand the difference between my two functions and why one updates it and the other does not.

**Edit:** Here's the `showCart()` function:

```
void ShoppingCart::showCart(){

    list<ItemOrdered> :: iterator i;
    int j=1;
    for(i=orderList.begin(); i!=orderList.end(); ++i){
        cout<<j<<". "<<i->getItem()->getName()<<" ("<<i->getQuantity()<<")"<<endl;
        j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the function wit a debugger to make sure the object is being found?

Comment: Seems the obvious thing to investigate, your `if` statement is never true. Why? Because you have a bug somewhere else.

Comment: I would check what @user4581301 said and make sure you're actually finding the element, but I would also either bail out of the for loop once found or at least change it to `z=orderList.erase(z);` which will update the iterator once the item is removed.

Comment: Is the list being used a `std::list`? If so, why not use the `std::find()` as well? That function would be something like three lines or so.

Comment: I tried `cout<<orderList.size()<<endl;` inside the **if** and the size of the list actually decreased by 1 so **for** and **if** both worked

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the code you've shown contains all the information needed to find the bug? If you could extract just enough from your real code to create a [mcve] it'd be a lot easier for people to help.

Comment: @AndreasKostas That `for` loop is fundamentally flawed.  You are incrementing a possible invalidated iterator `z` when `++z` is executed.  If you erased an item, that `z` iterator is no good anymore, thus `++z` is undefined behavior.

Comment: Let us see the function `showCart`

Comment: @AndreasKostas We have no idea, when, where, or how any of these functions are called.  In addition, you're using pointers and we have no idea, again, where, when, and how those pointers are initialized.  We need to see a [mcve].  But regardless, you need to fix your code first, as pointed out in the answer I gave before even going forward.  Your erasure code is invalid as it stands now.

Answer (score 0):

You have one issue with your code that erases from a `std::list`, and that is you are accessing an invalid iterator if the item is erased.

```
void ShoppingCart::removeItemOrdered(Item* orderedItem){
    list<ItemOrdered> :: iterator z;
    for(z = orderList.begin(); z != orderList.end(); ++z){
        if(z->getItem()->getID() == orderedItem->getID()){
            orderList.erase(z); // <-- z is now invalidated
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that `z` will become invalidated if the erasure occurs, thus when the loop performs `++z`, the `z` that will be incremented is no longer valid.

The proper way to write the loop is to reassign the iterator when an erasure occurs, as outlined [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase):

```
void ShoppingCart::removeItemOrdered(Item* orderedItem){
    list<ItemOrdered> :: iterator z;
    for(z = orderList.begin(); z != orderList.end(); ){
        if(z->getItem()->getID() == orderedItem->getID()){
            z = orderList.erase(z); // <-- z is now assigned to the next item
        }
        else
          ++z;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the case. Whatever change I make to `orderList`, it doesn't get updated. Although it really does change inside `removeItemOrdered()` it seems like  `showCart()` doesn't load the new `orderList`. It's like whatever change I make to `orderList` eventually gets stuck inside the function

Comment: Well, your code is wrong.  You were lucky you got as far as you did without a crash occurring.  The answer points out an obvious bug in your code that you have to fix before even considering anything else.